# Updating one column from the column of another table

Tags: sql, sql-update

Hi i want to update a column with the column of other table taking some decision
Here is my code

```
update STOCKS 
    set SE_QTY_L2 = (   

      select SE_QTY_L2  

      from STOCKS  
      join 
      VITEM on VITEM.Code= STOCKS.SE_ITEM_CODE 
      and SE_UNIT = VITEM.[First Unit] and VITEM.[Max Level] = 3  


      )   from STOCKS    
      join 
      VITEM on VITEM.Code= STOCKS.SE_ITEM_CODE 
      and SE_UNIT = VITEM.[First Unit] and VITEM.[Max Level] = 3
```

when i run this query , following error is thrown:

**ERROR**

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the
>   subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as
>   an expression

Comment: Think about what you are trying to do - you want to set `SE_QTY_L2` to potentially multiple values for a single record. You will need to be clearer on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to to update one column with the column of other table using where clause

Comment: @user1448783 yes, you already made that clear in your question.  The point is *what are you actually trying to do*?  Explain the actual task you want to accomplish, and also explain the structure of the tables and how they relate to each other..

Comment: @user1448783 The error is fairly self explanatory, and I have told you what it means. Now you need to explain what you want a little more clearly.

Comment: Dear i want to do the following:

Comment: update STOCKS 
        set SE_QTY_L2  = ( select  
             VITEM.Code_CODE
         from STOCKS  
         join 
          VITEM on VITEM.Code= STOCKS.SE_ITEM_CODE 
          
          
          ) from STOCKS    
          join 
          VITEM on VITEM.Code= STOCKS.SE_ITEM_CODE

Comment: @user1448783 Posting your code in a comment does not explain things any better. This is my final try - explain what you do not understand about my original comment and also what you want to achieve.

Comment: dear i am selecting one column after joining two tables and then seting in the column that's name is SE_QTY_L2 in stock table

Comment: "i am selecting one column after joining two tables and then seting in the column that's name is SE_QTY_L2 in stock table" - we know that! But why are you doing that? We want you to explain the real-world problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

What is your output when you run;

```
SELECT Code, [First Unit], [Max Level]
FROM Vitem
WHERE [Max Level] = 3
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

If you have more than one row, then it means that you will be returning more than one match for your UPDATE criteria, which is why your subquery is blowing up.  You need to look for a unique combination of rows from your source table.